# how can i escape the space in between using regex for rest i have to put a \ for each special characters

Tags: regex

let me know how can i escape the space in between, it may confuse , even if “\ “ is equivalent to “ “, rest for all special character i want to put a  "\"

```
Input
    "$An is h(Stack%1231+#$124{}".replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z0-9])", "\\\\$1" )
output
    \$An\ is\ h\(Stack\%1231\+\#\$124\{\}
Desired output should be like this, this is want i want to achieve using regex
    \$An is h\(Stack\%1231\+\#\$124\{\}
```

What extra expression do i need to provide in addition of ([^a-zA-Z0-9])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the space to the negated character class so it will not be escaped:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]
```